# Why doesn't this regular expression match in this string?

Tags: python, regex

I want to be able to replace a string in a file using regular expressions. But my function isn't finding a match. So I've mocked up a test to replicate what's happening.

I have defined the string I want to replace as follows:

`string = 'buf = O_strdup("ONE=001&TYPE=PUZZLE&PREFIX=EXPRESS&");'`

I want to replace the "TYPE=PUZZLE&PREFIX=EXPRESS&" part with something else. NB. the string won't always contain exactly "PUZZLE" and "PREFIX" in the original file, but it will be of that format ).

So first I tried testing that I got the correct match.

```
 obj = re.search(r'TYPE=([\^&]*)\&PREFIX=([\^&]*)\&', string)
 if obj:
    print obj.group()
 else:
    print "No match!!"
```

Thinking that `([\^&]*)` will match any number of characters that are NOT an ampersand.
But I always get "No match!!".

However,
`obj = re.search(r'TYPE=([\^&]*)', string)`

returns me "TYPE="

Why doesn't my first one work?

Comment: very first change should be  [^&]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the `^` sign is escaped with `\` the following part: `([\^&]*)` matches any sequence of these characters: ^, &.

Try replacing it with `([^&]*)`.

Comment: *"... matches any sequence of these characters: \, ^, &."* Not a backslash, just `^` and `&`.

Answer (score 1):

In my regex tester, this does work: `'TYPE=(.*)\&PREFIX=(.*)\&'`

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
obj = re.search(r'TYPE=(?P<type>[^&]*?)&PREFIX=(?P<prefix>[^&]*?)&', string)
```

The `?P<some_name>` is a named capture group and makes it a little bit easier to access the captured group, `obj.group("type") -->> 'PUZZLE'`

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to use the functions [`urlparse.parse_qsl()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urlparse.html#urlparse.parse_qsl) and [`urllib.urlencode()`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) instead of regular expressions.  The code will be less error-prone:

```
from urlparse import parse_qsl
from urllib import urlencode
s = "ONE=001&TYPE=PUZZLE&PREFIX=EXPRESS&"
a = parse_qsl(s)
d = dict(TYPE="a", PREFIX="b")
print urlencode(list((key, d.get(key, val)) for key, val in a))
# ONE=001&TYPE=a&PREFIX=b
```